# I am using mp chart library for android and want that my maximum draw value to be on top of line and min draw value to be above the line

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, styles, linechart

It wiil be great also to put margin there.
I am attaching also 2 sc .[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Find the minValue and maxValue then the set the axisMin and axisMax values.

```
//use getAxisRight for right Y axis
YAxis leftAxis = lineChart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(minValue);

//above line would be the same except
//"1" should be calculated and not hard coded
leftAxis.setAxisMaximum(maxValue - 1);
```